# Is this degree of lifting/rippling normal for a newly installed roof?

Tags: roof, roofing, inspection

Had a roof replacement done recently including new underlayment, architectural shingles, and flashing.

I'm noticing a number of red flags such as visible/exposed keyways between shingles.

However, one element I'm unsure about is the amount of rippling and ease with which shingles can be lifted. To my untrained eye this looks subpar and susceptible to lifting from wind.

From the video, should I be able to lift up shingles this easily? It takes next to no effort to lift the shingles up several inches off the roof.

In addition to the lifting, the rippling that I'm talking about can be better seen in the image linked.

Image:

- https://imagebin.ca/v/5iVHFYEJVl4i

Video:

- https://vimeo.com/483346754
- https://vimeo.com/483346752

[I would upload these to diy.stackexchange.com directly, but they exceed the file size limit.]

Comment: I can’t see the shingles either, but how many nails in each? If you live in a high wind area, there should be 6 nails per shingle.

Comment: You just had the work done it will take a hot day or two for things to seal up. I don’t see anything wrong arc80 is supposed to have a “lumpy” appearance , quit messing with it or your untrained hands will be breaking the shingles.

Comment: How recently? Looks like a cold day so the tar/sealant on the back side would be naturally loose allowing for such free-play. Once you have a layer of snow then wind won't be an issue. Wait for the summer months so that everything can seal itself up like @EdBeal mentioned. Aside from that you're probably going to cause damage yourself well before the wind does.